# Strange import behaviour when executing from Volume on Mac

Tags: python, google-drive-shared-drive

Google File Stream is a tool for syncing my Google Drive files to my Mac. It displays itself as an external Volume in Finder. If I have a simple python script, I can execute it normally. However, when I try to import another module that exists in the same directory on the volume, I get an import error. For example:

#### main.py:

```
import foo
print('hi')
```

#### foo.py:

```
def bar():
    return 1
```

#### Running:

```
> cd /Volumes/GoogleDrive/My\ Drive/Project
> ls
> main.py    foo.py
> python3 main.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import foo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

Even weirder:

#### main.py

```
import os            # importing standard modules always worked
print(os.listdir())  # import error returns if this line is removed!!!

import foo           # no error?!
print(foo.bar())     # prints 1
```

The import error disappears in this code. However if you remove `print(os.listdir())`, the import error returns. Also, `os.listdir()` returns an empty list which is unexpected.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have an `__init__.py` in that directory? Otherwise python will not treat that dir as a module

Comment: @wiesion the code works fine in my home directory without an `__init__.py` so I don't think that is the issue. I only get the error when I execute it inside the Volume. This also wouldn't explain why the code only works if I import a standard library module and call a function from it.

Comment: That sounds really weird - did you try to mark that specific folder (or the entire sync folder) as "Available offline"? Could be that the file gets downloaded/available only on demand (Which `os.listdir()` is probably triggering)

Comment: @wiesion good suggestion however I'm afraid I've already tried that. Making the files available offline does not fix the issue.